# file_exists() does not run

Tags: php

```
$myfilepath =  SITEROOT."/uploads/vaibhav_photo/thumbnail/".$user_avatar['thumbnail'];
if(file_exists($myfilepath))
{
  echo "file exist";
}
else
{
  echo "file does not exist";
}
```

It always goes to else part even though file is present.

if anybody have an alternate option for this in PHP please reply as fast as possible,

Comment: Does `SITEROOT` contain a file path? By the way, requests for a fast reply are frowned upon here, you'll fare better without them.

Comment: can you please send your directory structure and the relevant part of you web server configuration (root home for example).

Comment: $myfilepath =  "http://www.example.com/uploads/vaibhav_photo/thumbnail/".$user_avatar['thumbnail'];
it shows the path for that file when i echo $myfilepath

Comment: If `SITEROOT` is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, you need remove the first slash from the following path eg: `SITEROOT."uploads/vaibhav_phot....`

Comment: when i echo $myfilepath it shows http://www.example.com/uploads/vaibhav_photo/thumbnail/20110224193543color-taj-sample-colorize.jpg but it goes to else part even though image is existed

Answer (score 6):

[`file_exists`](http://php.net/file_exists) works on file paths only. `http://` URLs are not supported.

Comment: that's not true anymore, since PHP 5.0 some protocol wrappers may be used to access different kind of URL, see : http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: @Sarfraz @Krtek http is not among them: `Supports stat(): no`

Comment: @Sarfraz nope: From the manual page on file_exists: "As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers for a listing of which wrappers support stat() family of functionality." http:// does *not* support the `stat()` family of functionality.

Comment: @Sarfraz @Krtek, Pekka is correct, http://au.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php. You can plainly see `Supports stat(): no`

Comment: when I use fopen($myfilepath,"r") it works but when image not found it gives error like this 
Warning: fopen(http://www.example.com/uploads/vaibhav_photo/thumbnail/20110224193543color-taj-sample-colorize.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/dealheist/includes/classes/class.myphotogallery.php on line 108

Comment: @user yes, that is a valid way, but if this is on the same server, it is a dumb thing to do, as it is performance intensive to start a HTTP request. Always use file paths when possible

Answer (score 0):

`$myfilepath =  SITEROOT.DS.'uploads'.DS.'vaibhav_photo'.DS.'thumbnail'.DS.$user_avatar['thumbnail'`];

NOTE::`SITEROOT` have actual root path and `DS` is constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

Answer (score 0):

Pekka is correct that `file_exists` does not support http protocol.

You can however use [file_get_contents](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
if(file_get_contents($myfilepath)) {
    echo "file exist";
}
```

By default this pulls back the entire contents of the file. If this is not what you want you can optimise this by adding some flags:

```
if(file_get_contents($myfilepath, false, null, 0, 1)) {
    echo "file exist";
}
```

This syntax will return the first character if it exists.

Comment: updated my answer because Pekka is correct about `stat` not supporting `file_exists`

Answer (score 0):

Check what your working directory is with [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php).

Your path

```
example.com/uploads/etc/etc.jpg
```

is interpreted relative to the current directory. That's likely to be something like

```
/var/www/example.com
```

so you ask `file_exists()` about a file named

```
/var/www/example.com/example.com/uploads/etc/etc.jpg
```

You need to either figure out the correct absolute path (add the path containing all site roots in front of `SITEROOT`) or the correct relative path (relative to the directory your script is in, without a leading `/`).

**tl;dr**: try

```
$myfilepath = 'uploads/etc/etc.jpg';
```